# How to read ePubs on a first generation iPad

Tags: ipad, epub

My father has a 1st generation iPad. I can't seem to find a single eBook reader that is compatible. iBooks should have a compatible version, but it won't install it.

I have read about using iTunes to sync older versions, but his Mac mini is so old it won't even 'see' the iPad on iTunes.

Any ideas?

Comment: The 1st gen iPad seems to me to have very quickly become the "forgotten child".

Comment: Marvin, if you can get an old version. Or, alas, the now defunct Stanza, which was a fabulous reader app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeyondPrint Reader
iTunes Store link: https://itunes.apple.com/br/app/beyondprint-reader/id464926033?mt=8

Installed and working!